# DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged. Error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

whenever i run my code (modal thingy) it gives me the error: DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.

heres the code:

```
// Modal Handler
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {

  if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

  if (interaction.customId === 'warnmodal') {
    const reason = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('reason');

    const dmEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("Blue")
    .setDescription(`<:success_checkmark:1092216874768547922> You have been *warned* in ***${interaction.guild.name}***. | ${reason}`)

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("Blue")
    .setDescription(`<:success_checkmark:1092216874768547922> ${interaction.user.tag} has been ***warned***. | ${reason}`)

    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });

    await interaction.user.send({embeds: [dmEmbed] }).catch(err => {
        return;
    })
```

main modal thing (its a context menu)

```
const { ContextMenuCommandBuilder, ApplicationCommandType, EmbedBuilder, ModalBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle } = require(`discord.js`);
const { QuickDB } = require(`quick.db`);
const db = new QuickDB();

module.exports = {
    data: new ContextMenuCommandBuilder()
    .setName('Warn User')
    .setType(ApplicationCommandType.User),
    async execute (interaction) {

        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setTitle("Warn Menu")
        .setCustomId('warnmodal')

        const reason = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId('reason')
        .setRequired(true)
        .setLabel("Reason for the warn")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(reason)

        modal.addComponents(firstActionRow)
        interaction.showModal(modal)

    }
}
```

I tried restarting but I dont know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged error can happen if you are trying to send a reply to the same interaction that has already been acknowledged.

To resolve this, you can add a check to determine if the interaction has already been responded to, and if so, then return from the interaction handler to avoid sending another reply.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
  // Return if interaction has already been replied to
  if (interaction.replied) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Your code here
});

In this example, the interactionCreate event handler checks if the interaction has already been replied to by checking the interaction.replied property. If it has, then the return statement immediately exits the handler and prevents the code from trying to send another reply.

if this doesn't work then this line of code maybe effecting it:

await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });

The error is indicating that the interaction has already been acknowledged and a reply has been sent. This could happen if you are trying to send another reply to the same interaction such as sending a second interaction.reply().

To resolve this, you can add a check to determine if the interaction has already been responded to, and if so, then return from the interaction handler to avoid sending another reply. Here's an example of how to do this:

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  // Ignore non-Modal interactions
  if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;
 
  // Return if interaction has already been replied to
  if (interaction.replied) {
    return;
  }
  
  if (interaction.customId === 'warnmodal') {
    const reason = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('reason');
    const dmEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("Blue")
    .setDescription(`<:success_checkmark:1092216874768547922> You have been *warned* in ***${interaction.guild.name}***. | ${reason}`)
 
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor("Blue")
    .setDescription(`<:success_checkmark:1092216874768547922> ${interaction.user.tag} has been ***warned***. | ${reason}`)
 
    // Send reply
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
 
    // Send DM
    await interaction.user.send({embeds: [dmEmbed] }).catch(err => {
        return;
    })
  }
});

In this example, when the interactionCreate event is triggered, the code checks whether the interaction has already been replied to. If it has, then the code returns immediately and does not try to send another reply.
```